# delete value 0 in post meta

Tags: post-meta

I have a simple question. I have this code and its correct,

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'codigopostal', true);
if($meta != $empty) { echo "(".$meta.")"; } ?>
```

but when the user don't put nothing, value is 0. I want delete that value on frontpage.

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'codigopostal', true);
if($meta != $empty) {
    echo "(".$meta.")";
} 
else if($meta != 0) {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

I added else if... but is wrong.

Comment: I edited my question @G.M. Sorry for my english. If i put your code, give me errors in code.

Comment: i changed code of else but still not working. else if($meta != 0) { echo ""; } @G.M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is off-topic because your is a simple PHP error, not related to WordPress.

You are trying to check if a variable is empty using:

```
if ( $meta != $empty ) {
```

but this is not the right way, in fact this code compare the target variable `$meta` with another variable `$empty` that is not defined.

If you want to check if a variable is empty in PHP you have to use the [`empty` function](http://php.net/empty) so your code should be:

```
<?php
$postid = get_queried_object_id();
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'codigopostal', true);
if ( ! empty($meta) ) echo "(" . $meta . ")";
?>
```

Note I've used [`get_queried_object_id`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/) that return the id of the current queried post id without using global variables.

Comment: but with this code, in other post don't show nothing, including post with value. "(" . $meta . ")" don't show never.

Comment: Where you are using the code? in which template file? @VektorUnbreakable

Comment: index.php , single-pro.php , archive.php

Comment: the problem is, when the user don't put value in that field, the value is 0 and i want when value is 0, don't show nothing, but if value is other, show "(" . $meta . ")"

Comment: don't worry, the problem is because custom fields plugin created 0 value in number field. I puted that field like text and problem solved, not the best fixed but... really thanks

Comment: How can close this question? I'm new here.